# Is Perl's $| selecting the right buffer?

Tags: perl, buffer

I'm trying to change file sizes rapidly and running into issues where the file never made it to the right size. Is the code below operating like I think it is? Mainly is the `$|` operator actually choosing the `$fh` or is it choosing `STDOUT`?

```
# Open file, hot buffer
open(my $fh, '>>', $file_path) ||
   die 'Could not open temp file: '.$!;
$| = TRUE;

# Make file longer (div 2 because 
# we print 2 at a time)
print $fh "\r\n" x ($diff / 2);

# Wait for file system to catch
# up, then close file.
sleep 1;
close $fh;
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Also see [How do I flush/unbuffer an output filehandle? Why must I do this?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-flush/unbuffer-an-output-filehandle?-Why-must-I-do-this?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be thinking that this

```
$| = TRUE;
```

Sets `$|` to a true value. This is however wrong. If you were to enable warnings, you would get the following warning:

```
Argument "TRUE" isn't numeric in scalar assignment
```

And you would see that `$|` is in fact `0` (false). This is because `TRUE` is a bareword (unless some module with constants are loaded), which is interpreted as a string, which is converted to a number, which becomes zero `0` in this case. So instead do this:

```
$| = 1;
```

This particular variable can only have the values `1` or `0`. You can set it directly, in which case it affects the currently `select()`ed file handle (STDOUT by default). Or you can use object oriented notation

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);  # this is what you did
$fh->autoflush(1);     # this is what you want
```

So in your code above, you would need to do this for it to work as expected:

```
select($fh);
$| = 1;
```

Although you should know that when closing a file handle, all buffers affecting it are flushed.

Comment: That would be `$fh->autoflush(1);` in this case.

Comment: @cjm Yes, I noticed that.

Comment: Ahh, I like the object interface and I have 5.012 and warnings, so TRUE is a constant (just not in this segment). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EricFossum I still get a bareword warning for `TRUE` even if I `use 5.012`. Not sure what you are referring to there. But anyway, you're welcome.

Comment: 5.012 includes strict I'm pretty sure, and I mean "TRUE is a constant" because I declared it earlier. I just forgot it wasn't in this block, so you couldn't see it.